# How to create a file in a specific team drive or folder?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm using the [Google Drive API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v3/drive.files.create). I can't seem to get a file to get created in the drive that I want. It either creates a file in the root of my drive or gives me an error of "file not found".

Comment: you'll need to paste your code, and ideally an http trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Have Used Following javaScript Code in my project, it worked for me. Not sure  which language you are using.

```
function createFolder(parentid,folderName) {
var access_token = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().getAuthResponse().access_token;
var request = gapi.client.request({
    'path': '/drive/v2/files/',
    'method': 'POST',
    'headers': {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
    },
    'body': {
        "title": folderName,
        "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
        "parents": [{
            "kind": "drive#file",
            "id": parentid
        }]
    }

});
request.execute(function (resp) {
        console.error("createFolder", resp.error);
});
```

};

`parentid` is the id of the folder in which you want to create a folder(ex: `1eYTYMkptjn8K9Pu8_aGII-rF3-3Oymlo`)
and `folderName` is the name of the new folder
If you want to create other than the folder just change the `mimeType`